Apache Maven Assembly DependecySet Exclude JAR without Classifier (And keep my Classifier-JAR )
I am facing a problem since bumping from Apache Maven Assembly 3.3.0 to 3.7.0.
I build an EAR with Dependencies defined...
My JARs:

com.core.serverjar-11.1.2.jar
com.core.serverjar-11.1.2-genonce.jar

My Excludes:
<dependencySets>
<excludes>
<exclude>com.core:serverjar:jar:11.1.2<exclude>
<excludes>
</dependencySets>

The result was: com.core.serverjar-11.1.2.jar isn't in my EAR anymore but com.core.serverjar-11.1.2-genonce.jar is still there - it worked fine with Assembly 3.3.0.
With 3.7.0 both JARs wehre excluded.
I also tried to "include" the Genonce bevor and after the exclude -> same behaviour...
Any ideas how to get back to the old behaviour or a workaround to include my Genonce.jar without the "normal" JAR?
(I cannot change names)
Works until: 3.3.0
<dependencySets>
<excludes>
<exclude>com.core:serverjar:jar:11.1.2<exclude>
<excludes>
</dependencySets>

Try with include behind:
<dependencySets>
<excludes>
<exclude>com.core:serverjar:jar:11.1.2<exclude>
<excludes>
<includes>
<include>com.core:serverjar:jar:genonce:11.1.2<include>
<includes>
</dependencySets>

Try with include before:
<dependencySets>
<includes>
<include>com.core:serverjar:jar:genonce:11.1.2<include>
<includes>
<excludes>
<exclude>com.core:serverjar:jar:11.1.2<exclude>
<excludes>
</dependencySets>

